# how to calculate the size of the query bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are planned to use bigquery to store our datas. Maybe the size of tables is around 150GB.
But we need some informations before to start to use bigquery, especially for the price 
My questions are:
1-if we have around 150GB how much we have to paid per month for the storage data?
2-Could we have some informations about how to calculate the size for the streaming data, for the insert for example?
3-For the query, in the documentation, it's mentionned that the size is calculated by the size if data type.
So it means that it's based only by the data type or by addition the size of rows
For example: if i have a query
select field1,field2 from table1 and the result returns 10 rows
field1 is type integer
filed2 is type string
So the size of this query is 8bytes + 2bytes  or (8bytes+2bytes)*number of row of the result

Thank you so much for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Did you have chance to check below?

For #1 - [Storage Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage)
For #2 - [Data Size Calculation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data)
For #3 - [Query Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) and [Sample query costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#samplecosts)

in Short
 #1 - it will be $3 per month for storing 150GB. Those tables that are not edited for 90 consecutive days will become subject for Long term storage pricing

#3 - just to follow your way of thinking - it will be (8bytes+2bytes)*(**number of row in whole table**) Note  - `in whole table` not just `in the result`. So the cost will be the same no matter it is 1 row in result or 1000 rows in a result

Comment: but how to calculate for the query with left,right or inner join, between 2 or more tables

Comment: it is the same. you calculate size of involved columns for each table and sum them. note: the minimum is 10MB per table. meaning if you query just 1MB you will be billied for 10MB. Any size (per table) is rounded up to next 10MB

Comment: thank you for your reply, so it means size of each columns * total number of rows of each table

Comment: Yes. Sum of total scanned size for each table involved in join. Scanned size of table is: size of used/scanned columns * total number of rows rounded up to closest 10MB

Comment: ok i have voted, but according to you, is there any way to reduce the cost of query?

Comment: partitioning is the way you can explore - for example daily partitioning will help if you query for specific day or days so you can narrow down to specific tables. or you can partition by other significant attribute of your data - all depends on your data

Comment: ok thank you for your advice Mikhail Berlyant, but another question, if we use API of query, will we benefit  the cache result,cause cache result means 0byte of billing, if we use the same query data in the API

Comment: yes, but nothing happens just magically. you will need to make sure to follow recommendations in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#opting_out_of_query_caching